# How can I save the data from a vector of structs and load it on program start?

Tags: c++11, vector

I have given this problem a great attempt. After almost 6 hours of trying to get this working I have resorted to the internet and StackOverflow to be told my question is irrelevant and a duplicate, but here I am anyways trying to learn :)

Question: How can I save the data in my vector array (struct array) and load this data into the same array on program startup?

Description: I have been tasked with creating a program that will read data from a file. The task involves writing a program that uses a structure to store info in a file. I want to take the user entered info in my vector of structs and save it to a .txt file. The, when I open up my program again I want to load said data into the same array which is now empty due to the program just starting and continue where I left off.

Because my code is about 300 lines I have provided a link to pastebin instead.

https://pastebin.com/YBuhJCRu

Below is my attempt at saving the data from the vector to a file:

```
        ofstream output;
        output.open("save.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

        for(int h = 0; h < recordkeeper.size(); h++) {

            output.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&recordkeeper[h]), sizeof(struct inventory));

        }

        output.close();
```

Comment: Read about serialization data. Your problem is that `inventory` has `std::string` instance. `std::string` has internal pointer to data, by calling `output.write()` you save only value of this pointer into binary file, but not data pointed by this. You need to store in file content pointed by `std::string::c_str()`, easy way to do is to add header-length then put characters. `[length on 4 bytes][chars of string]` + others plain data of your `inventory` struct.

Comment: Im sorry, being pretty new to C++ I am unsure on how to do what you are saying in the actual code I have.